# Remove post_tag from default post type, add custom taxonomy

Tags: posts, tags

I've been searching for a while for an answer to this, but the results I find always deal with custom post types as opposed to the built-in 'post' post type.

I want to remove the default 'Post Tags' taxonomy from the built-in 'post' post type and then add my own custom taxonomy to replace it. Essentially, I have other custom post types using my custom taxonomy and I'd like to align the 'post' post type with them.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to edit the default post type though, any ideas how I would do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

to completely remove post tags: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8363082

if you want to remove post tags from posts, but keep on other custom post types:

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_register_post_tags' );

function my_register_post_tags() {
    register_taxonomy( 'post_tag', array( 'my_post_type_here' ) );
}
```

to add your own custom taxonomy to posts, use [register_taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy), setting the `$object_type` parameter to `post`.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but it seems to me like the link you provided will remove post_tag from ALL post types (default & custom).  I want to remove it from default only, and still have it available for other custom post types. Is that possible?

Comment: i've updated my answer to show this, you just pass in the names of the CPTs you wish to add post_tags to in the array.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks. Seems so simple now but I just couldn't wrap my head around it.